# Hide div on click: Where is the error?

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, getelementbyid, display

Can anybody tell me where is the error in my code? It doesn't do anything :-(

```
var contentclose = document.getElementById('contentclose');
contentclose.onclick = function() {
     var content = document.getElementById('content-wrap');
     content.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: In which context is the code run? Has everything loaded?

Comment: please show the html as well

Comment: Check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/x04jbcvj/. Your code is fine

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies, WOW! ;-)

I edited the jsfiddle to be like my original skript.... and now I saw where I had the mistake! There was just a silly "t" missing in id="contentclose". 

Aaaah silly me!! :-)